# How to make input and button stack on top of each others on mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn form-group">
      <select name="huge" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-default btn-fill btn-block">
        <option disabled> Search in...</option>
        <option value="1" selected>Songs </option>
        <option value="1">Bands</option>
        <option value="1">Drummers</option>
        <option value="1">Time Signatures</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-fill search-button" type="button">Search</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the different elements to stack on top of eachothers when going on mobile view. Right now, the search bar shrinks and become invisible on low resolution.

How can I do so that the 3 elements stack on top of eachothers when in mobile view?

PS: I'm using `bootstrap-select` for the select element.

Comment: Guess you need to use the column classes here, but for some reason I am not able to make them work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input-group with input field, select (silviomoreto) and button not displaying correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091380/input-group-with-input-field-select-silviomoreto-and-button-not-displaying-co)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to drop the `form-group` structure and use a row instead:

```css
.nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.input-block-level {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row nopadding">
  <div class="nopadding col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <select name="huge" class="form-control input-block-level" data-style="btn-default btn-fill btn-block">
      <option disabled>Search in...</option>
      <option value="1" selected>Songs</option>
      <option value="1">Bands</option>
      <option value="1">Drummers</option>
      <option value="1">Time Signatures</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="nopadding col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-block-level">
  </div>
  <div class="nopadding col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-fill search-button input-block-level" type="button">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar sometimes this stuff is a mystery :)

Comment: Yea yea, that's so true... There's literally no difference between your code and mine.